# How to remove class active from multiple active li (multiselect li)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created an `<ul> <li>` list. When you select each `<li>`, there will be active classes each. Now, my goal is how to deselect or remove the active class on the current selected `<li>` if it has active class already.

```js
$('.package_wrap li').click(function() {
    $('.package_wrap li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="package_wrap">
    <li class="active">foo1</li>
    <li class="active">foo2</li>
    <li class="active">foo3</li>
    <li>foo4</li>
    <li>foo5</li>
</ul>
```

Now, if I want to deselect `foo3` without removing the active class of `foo`1 and `foo2`. How can I do it?

In this event, it only select and deselect one `<li>` at a time. What I want is that I can multi select `<li>` or put active classes on them and can deselect one `<li>` without affecting other `<li>`.

[actual code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yOoT.png)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your question isn't clear as to what you want. You've basically asked us to write something without clearly specifying what that is. However, given that you've tagged this as jQuery, you probably wan to look at the methods listed in [Category: Class Attribute](https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/). Note also that making considerable assumptions about what you want, based on what's commonly desired, this is a question with many duplicates. You might want to spend some time searching to see if you can find a question which already covers what you desire to do.

Comment: I put a sample code in it

Comment: @Makyen, here is the sample html code for it.

Comment: @Rover02 That helps significantly, but you haven't defined how the code that's supposed to be doing this is being called. Is is an event listener that's placed somewhere and the user clicks on the `<li>` that is supposed to change? Is it just out of the blue that you want to do this? Is it because the `<li>` is the 3rd one? Is it because the text content of the `<li>` is "foo3"? These things matter, because it determines how that element is selected.

Comment: @Makyen, here I put an event

Comment: I suggest you look at [`.toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/). You say you don't want to remove the `active` class, then just don't use `.removeClass()` to remove it.

Comment: @Makyen

I have tried this:

`$('.package_wrap li').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
`});`


it's not working

Comment: @Rover02 What's not working? What is it doing that you think it should not be doing? What is it not doing that you think it should be doing? The code you have in the comment does what I understand your question to be. If it's not doing what you want, please [edit] your question to be more clear as to what you desire to have happen.

Comment: @Makyen that is just it. I don't know why it is not working. There no other classes aside from "active"

Comment: @Rover02 I'm not asking you to explain *why* it's not working. I'm saying you need to describe more accurately, in more detail, what you *expect*/*want* to happen and what you see that's not happening or is happening that does/does not meet those expectations (i.e. *how* it's not working). The code in your earlier comment, when I run it in the snippet instead of the event handler that's currently there, correctly does what you describe in the question, or at least how I understand what you wrote. Thus, if that's not what you want, then you need [edit] to be more clear as to what you do desire.

Comment: @Makyen no, what I meant was, I tried it on snippet, and it works like how I want it to happen. But when I tried to do it in my codes. It doesn't work. It doesn't toggle the active class. I dont know why.

Comment: @Makyen Is it because I put my <ul> list inside php. calling data from db dynamically. I think it will not affect it, right?

Comment: @Makyen, i put an image link for the actual code

Comment: Please don't use pictures of code. It makes it much, much harder to debug than it needs to be. Instead, [edit] your question to include your code as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: @Rover02 We, here, don't have enough information to be able to make any statements about code you haven't shown in the question. Obviously, if something works here and doesn't work in the code you are actually using, then something is affecting it, or the situations are not that similar in some other way.

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: @Makyen sorry for that. toggleClass is what I really need. it works here in the snippet. It is what I want to happen. I just dont know why it doesnt work in my code. But thank you for your help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

For you desire result you just need **toggleClass** instead of **remove** and **addClass**.

```js
$('.package_wrap li').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="package_wrap">
    <li class="active">foo1</li>
    <li class="active">foo2</li>
    <li class="active">foo3</li>
    <li>foo4</li>
    <li>foo5</li>
</ul>
```

I hope this will help.